# Attach values in a new column when a specific word is displayed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to create a new column based on the 'id' column and attach a value whenever a certain string is present.

**Data**

```
id  place
aa  ny
bb  ny
ci  ca
ci  ca
```

**Desired**

```
id  place   type
aa  ny      160
bb  ny      80
ci  ca      70
ci  ca      70
```

**Doing**

I am creating a dictionary that holds these values, however, I am not able to append these values in a new column

```
df.assign({'aa': '160', 'bb': '80', 'ci': '70'})
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map them:

```
df['type']=df['id'].map({'aa': '160', 'bb': '80', 'ci': '70'})
```

OR

replace them:

```
df['type']=df['id'].replace({'aa': '160', 'bb': '80', 'ci': '70'})
```

Comment: ah ok I was missing appending the column, let me try. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From your DataFrame :

```py
import pandas as pd

>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['aa', 'bb', 'ci', 'ci'], 
...                      'place': ['ny', 'ny', 'ca', 'ca']}, 
...                     index = [0, 1, 2, 3]) 
>>> df_1
    id  place
0   aa  ny
1   bb  ny
2   ci  ca
3   ci  ca
```

We can convert the `dict` to a `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> your_dict = {'aa': '160', 'bb': '80', 'ci': '70'}
>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_dict, orient='index', columns=['value']).reset_index(drop=False)
>>> df_2
    index   value
0   aa      160
1   bb      80
2   ci      70
```

And merge them :

```py
>>> df = pd.merge(df_1,
...               df_2,
...               how='left',
...               left_on=['id'],
...               right_on=['index'])            
>>> df.drop(['index'], axis=1)
    id  place   value
0   aa  ny      160
1   bb  ny      80
2   ci  ca      70
3   ci  ca      70
```